# Telnet timeout is occuring in perl

Tags: perl

I'm getting command timeout sometimes but sometimes the same command runs. Why is this happening?

```
$port = new Net::Telnet(
    Timeout     => 180,
    Errmode     => 'die',
    Dump_Log    => "board_dumplog.log",
    output_log  => "outputlog.log",
    input_log   => "inputlog.log",
);
$port->open("xx.xxx.xx.x") or die "Cannot open telnet:$!";
$port->print("\n");
$port->waitfor('/login:/');
$port->print("root \n");
$port->cmd("./ne unittest");
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably timing out because the peer does not send what you expected it to send. To debug this kind of problems use input_log or dump_log like documented. From the documentation of waitfor:

> Use dump_log() to debug when this method keeps timing-out and you don't think it should.